# Problem with timedatectl and network time synchronisation in 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, services, time, systemd

I have a dual-boot machine with Windows and Xubuntu 16.04. Because of Windows, the hardware clock is set to local time, so I had to use timedatectl to make Xubuntu aware of that after the upgrade to 16.04. The problem is that either I am not able to enable network time synchronization, or timedatectl is giving me wrong output.

`systemctl list-units | grep time` seems to indicate that the network time service is running:

```
systemd-timesyncd.service
    loaded active running   Network Time Synchronization 
time-sync.target
    loaded active active    System Time Synchronized
```

At the same time, `timedatectl` returns this:

```
Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Despite what the documentation says, `sudo timedatectl set-ntp true` has no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the complete output of `timedatectl`? I get the current time as well. `ntp: no` just tells you that you didn't install `ntp`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a bug with 16.04. I had the same problem and simply installing ntp helped.

```
sudo apt install ntp
```

After a reboot `timedatectl` showed ntp sync enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a conflict with ntpdate being on the machine as well. If you ONLY install `ntp` but not `ntpdate`, then `ntp` is allowed to work. With both on the machine, `ntp` won't stay up on next reboot.

Seems related to this [bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs%40lists.ubuntu.com/msg4946115.html).